# Photoshop CS6: Small Image Floating At Top-Left of Primary Image Window

Tags: image, adobe, photoshop

I don't remember how it started, although I believe it began after using 3D tools at one point. I was looking for TWO answers, if possible:

For some reason, I find this hard to describe in words, so following the description is a link to a screenshot.

When I open, or create a new image followed by pasting an image from the Clipboard, in Photoshop, there is this zone at the top-left of the image window containing a smaller image, which is surrounded by an area that appears to be transparent - but when clicked on, or the window itself is moved, this "picture-in-picture" feature disappears - then comes back after the dragging is finished.

**SCREENSHOT:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bjg8.jpg

> 1) What is this "feature" named?
>
> 2) How do I turn it off?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can tell what you hit, or where this is located from the image you shared... can you upload a more comprehensive interface snapshot? It feels like you simply have a duplicate layer on top of your main layer...

Perhaps take a look at your `workspace` settings and try going to `essential` and see if that preview panel goes away.

[image]